# PHP: for loop and birthday date

Tags: php

I have a little problem

birthday´s get stored as DATE in the MySQL database.

DATE is 00-00-00

and now when i make the select options, i did it with a for loop:

```
<?php
$month_names = array("januar", "februar", "marts", "april", "maj", "juni", "juli", "august", "september", "oktober", "november", "december");
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    echo "<option ";
    if ($i == $month) {
        echo "selected=\"selected\" ";
    }
    echo "value=\"$i\">", $month_names[$i-1], "</option>\n";
}
?>
```

This works, but gives me 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 as values.

I need to have it like this 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a condition like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    echo "<option ";
    if ($i == $month) {
        echo "selected=\"selected\" ";
    }

    if ($i < 10) {
      echo "value=\"0$i\">", $month_names[$i-1], "</option>\n";
    }
    else{
      echo "value=\"$i\">", $month_names[$i-1], "</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say, that a condition like this is a little to much. I really like Tim's solution and would have done SimpleCoder's solution otehrwise.

Comment: @Kau-Boy: Agreed this is what came to my mind at the time of writing :)

Answer (score 4):

Replace the 7th line with the following:

```
printf("value=\"%02d\">%s</option>\n", $i, $month_names[$i-1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`str_pad()` is what you're after.

http://www.php.net/str_pad

Instead of printing `$i`, you need to use

```
echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

which will pad the string with zeros on the left-hand size until it is two characters long.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use string formatting functions:

Change

```
echo "value=\"$i\">", $month_names[$i-1], "</option>\n";
```

to

```
echo "value=\"$i\">", ($month_names[$i-1] < 10 ? $month_names[$i-1] : "0" . $month_names[$i-1]), "</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to prepend the value string with a '0' if it's less than 10.